# How to read files in python

Tags: python-3.x, file-read

If my file content is (filename:test):

```
00001069: 04 33 c0 eb 42 53 8b 1e 6b 00 6a 04 6a 02 6a 00

00001078: 6a 02 68 00 00 00 70 68 38 30 00 10 ff 15 08 20
```

How do I read the file into content

ex :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(content,'test')
```

thank you

Comment: Can you post expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pd.read_csv`

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('test', sep=" ", header=None)
print(data)
```

Gives you,

```
          0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
0  00001069:  04  33  c0  eb  42  53  8b  1e  6b   0  6a   4  6a   2  6a   0
1  00001078:  6a   2  68  00   0   0  70  68  38  30  00  10  ff  15  08  20
```

You may label the columns too,

```
data.columns = ["Code", "Elem 1", "Elem 2", "Elem 3", "Elem 4", "Elem 5", "Elem 6", "Elem 7", "Elem 8",
                "Elem 9", "Elem 10", "Elem 11", "Elem 12", "Elem 13", "Elem 14", "Elem 15", "Elem 16"]
print(data)
```

Which gives you,

```
        Code Elem 1  Elem 2 Elem 3  ... Elem 13  Elem 14  Elem 15 Elem 16
0  00001069:     04      33     c0  ...      6a        2       6a       0
1  00001078:     6a       2     68  ...      ff       15       08      20
```

Comment: but i get **DtypeWarning: Columns (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16) have mixed types. Specify dtype option on import or set low_memory=False.**....how can i set types..

Comment: in Repl.it website is "OK"

`contents =[datas,"TEST"]

results=[]
results.append(contents)
df = pd.DataFrame(data=results)`

but in Microsoft ML get Error :
NotImplementedError('Python Bridge conversion table not implemented for type [{0}]'.format(value.getType()))

Comment: @MichaelWu you can read this up https://stackoverflow.com/a/27232309/12128167. It will help for your DtypeWarning. I have not used Microsoft ML, you meant Azure ML? This question leads to your error https://stackoverflow.com/a/52637531/12128167, try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Use pandas as stated above by Hj Sin
 You can visit this site to read more about pandas and how to import various type of data  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html